# Combine rows into one ohlc row if time is the same?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have been experimenting with `resampling`(60S) data from tick `database` to another database called `min`.

I took a `to_excel` of both databases by loading into `pandas`.

In the `min` dataframe:

```
       timestamp           open      high      low       close
47759 2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468.00  30473.90  30440.15  30445.00
47758 2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468.00  30473.90  30440.15  30450.00
47758 2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468.00  30473.90  30440.15  30455.00
47758 2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468.00  30473.90  30440.15  30460.00
47758 2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468.00  30479.00  30440.15  30479.00
```

And ofcourse there are numerous rows like the above with different timestamps.

I am wondering how can I combine all these together to get only 1 row with the correct `open, high, low, close`.

The process can't be time consuming as this has to be done for signal processing.

Comment: `df.unstack()` or`df.stack()`?

Comment: How do you determine the "correct" open, high, low, close per timestamp?

Comment: @Chris if time is the same, the highest `high` will be high. Lowest low will be the low and close will be the last row close value. Open will be first row open value.

Comment: @ansev thanks for the suggestion. I am reading about `df.unstack()` and `df.stack()` now.

Comment: maybe something like `df.groupby(df['timestamp']).agg({'open' : 'first', 'high' : 'max', 'low' : 'min', 'close' : 'last'})`

Comment: @Sid don't think so, you should only get the unique timestamps with the groupby, it works with your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.agg` and pass a dictionary of columns with your intended aggregation metric after an initial `groupby`

```
print(df)

     timestamp   open     high       low  close
0  2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468  30473.9  30440.15  30445
1  2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468  30473.9  30440.15  30450
2  2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468  30473.9  30440.15  30455
3  2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468  30473.9  30440.15  30460
4  2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468  30479.0  30440.15  30479

df1 = df.groupby(df['timestamp']).agg
           ({'open' : 'first', 'high' : 'max', 'low' : 'min', 'close' : 'last'})
print(df1)
                          open     high       low  close
timestamp                                           
2019-11-04 14:23:00  30468  30479.0  30440.15  30479
```

if you wan't to ignore the time and just focus on date you can do

```
df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.date).agg
           ({'open' : 'first', 'high' : 'max', 'low' : 'min', 'close' : 'last'})
```

​